# Block keystrokes from a specific keyboard

Tags: winapi, capture, keystroke

I would like to block all keystrokes that are coming from a specific keyboard (identified by its HID/Name, so its low level stuff I guess) before they reach the focused application. But I'm still using this disabled keyboard (I'm getting the keystrokes). I think I need an application's hook but I don't know how to do that. Maybe you can give me some useful link?

Regards,

EDIT:

I think I need a low-level hook, because general hook (I mean hook all the existing window & threads) aren't available in the .net framework, concerning the user-space.
Moreover, I use RAWINPUT to get typed keystrokes from the keyboard. So if I make a hook to block keystroke from a specific device, could the hook block the RAWINPUT as well?

Comment: I guess setWindowHookEx is only for a specific handle/process. I want to always hook the top focused process. Maybe I can try to get a sort of "focus changed" event, but I didn't found any nice information about that.

Comment: This program seems to do what I want, but I can't understand how the programmer did.
http://nate.dynalias.net/dev/keyboardredirector.rails

Answer (score 0):

An application can distinguish the source of the input by [getting raw input data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However the application needs to handle WM_INPUT instead of WM_CHAR, WM_MOUSEMOVE, or WM_APPCOMMAND.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question. What I'm trying to do is to forbid the focused window (so it is not my application) to receive data from a specific device (like a keyboard). I'm pretty sure I need to hook the focused window.